# Typescript: How to use Map with dynamic value types?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, rxjs

I'm trying to implement a "cache service" in Typescript. The main "bucket" for the cache should me a `Map`. So far I came up with this:

```
interface CacheItem {
  value: Observable<any>;
  // validUntil: Date; // removed for simplification
}

private readonly cacheMap = new Map<string, CacheItem>();

public cachify<T>(cacheKey: string, cacheableFunction: () => Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    const itemExists = this.cacheMap.has(cacheKey);

    if (!itemExists) {
      this.cacheMap.set(cacheKey, {
        value: cacheableFunction().pipe(shareReplay())
      });
    }

    return this.cacheMap.get(cacheKey).value;
}
```

Then it can be used like this:

```
return this.cacheService
    .cachify('great-cache-key', () => fetchSomethingNice);
```

So far this works properly. Now I'd like to remove the usage of `any`. So I changed the service part to this:

```
interface CacheItem<T> { // T here
  value: Observable<T>; // and T here
}

private readonly cacheMap = new Map<string, CacheItem<unknown>>(); // unknown here because we now have to provide a type for CacheItem
```

The initialization has to be changed too because we never know about the type **inside** of the service.
With this, `cachify` will give me an error on the last line (`return this.cacheMap...`):

```
Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T>'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'.
```

I kind of do understand that T and unknown together are problematic but have no idea on how to fix it.

**Edit**
I created a stackblitz that shows the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-siunfk?devToolsHeight=33&file=index.html

Comment: Does this question depend on rxjs?  If so you might want to tag it as such; if not, maybe you should replace references to `Observable` with something native or something you define.  Ideally you'd provide a [mre] that others can just paste as-is into their own IDEs and immediately get to work on the issue; third-party types or undeclared types and values (like `isFuture` and `shareReplay` etc) are impediments to doing this.  Could you possibly [edit] to make it easier for us to work with?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the suggestion. I just added a stackblitz link.
I'm not sure if rxjs actually is relevant but still added it to be more clear.

Comment: If it turns out not to be relevant you *might* want to remove it, since those of us who don't have experience with it will be less likely to engage.  Also, the [mre] should be available as plaintext in the question itself and not only available as an external link (although such an IDE link is a nice supplement).  Good luck!

Comment: Does define the class to `class CacheService<T>`  and the map to `Map<string, CacheItem<T>>` works?

Answer (score 0):

You will need an `as` or some other escape hatch here because the type of `cacheMap` doesn’t know the type of each individual cached item.

You could perhaps write a strongly typed cache something like this:

```
type CacheMap = {
    greatCacheKey?: CacheItem<SomethingNice>
    gorgeousCacheKey?: CacheItem<DeliciousTreat>
    ...
}

function cachify<Key extends keyof CacheMap>(key: Key, cacheableFunction: () => Observable<CacheMap[Key]>) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure how that translates to the values and not only the keys of my map entries? I also just added a stackblitz that shows my issue.

Comment: Additional context: I don't want to define all the keys in the service...

Comment: reasonable! then you will need to use `as`, `any` or some other type assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Your first version, with

```
interface CacheItem {
  value: Observable<any>;
  // validUntil: Date; // removed for simplification
}
```

works properly, in my opinion, since it states that a `CacheItem` can store `any` type of value.

At the same time a code fragment like this

```
const instance = new CacheService();
instance
  .cachify('asdfasdf', () => of('resolve basic string value :)'))
  .subscribe((value) => {
    // See how it's correctly typed as string, also works with any other type.
    console.log(value);
  });
```

the type of the variable `value` is inferred correctly to be `string`.

If you, for whatever reason, need to get rid of `any`, then you need to elevate the type parameter at class level.
Elevating the type parameter (as suggested by @Jerryh001) to the class level removes the need to use `unknown` and makes the code compile.

This is the version that compiles.

```
class CacheService<T> {
  private readonly cacheMap = new Map<string, CacheItem<T>>();
  public cachify(
    cacheKey: string,
    cacheableFunction: () => Observable<T>
  ): Observable<T> {
    const itemExists = this.cacheMap.has(cacheKey);

    if (!itemExists) {
      this.cacheMap.set(cacheKey, {
        value: cacheableFunction().pipe(shareReplay()),
      });
    }

    return this.cacheMap.get(cacheKey).value;
  }
}
```

In this last version though, you have to fix the type at the level of `CacheService`, which means that an instance of `CacheService` can store only values of one particular type. To me this appears to be a less flexible solution.

Comment: I can't get it working like this.. Can you provide a stackblitz based on mine?
Thanks for your support.

Comment: This is your [stackblitz corrected](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-p6dlux?file=index.ts) by elevating the type parameter T to the class level.

Comment: But now values are `unknown` on lines 32 and 39?

Comment: You are right, I did not notice that. If you elevate the type parameter to the class level, then you have to specify the type of the instance of `CacheService`, which is a less flexible solution than the first one which uses `any`. I have updated my response.

Answer (score 0):

Just infer the return type explicitly from `cachify<T>`

```
return this.cacheMap.get(cacheKey).value as Observable<T>;
```

Cleaner code:

```
interface ICache<T> {
  value$: Observable<T>;
  expiry: number;
}

class CacheService {
  private readonly cacheMap = new Map<string, ICache<unknown>>();
  private readonly CACHE_SIZE = 1;
  private readonly CACHE_EXPIRY_INTERVAL = 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 minutes

  public cachify<T>(key: string, value$: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
    if (!this.cached(key)) this.set<T>(key, value$);

    return this.get<T>(key);
  }

  private cached(key: string): boolean {
    if (!this.cacheMap.has(key)) return false;

    if (this.cacheMap.get(key).expiry < Date.now()) {
      this.cacheMap.delete(key);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  private set<T>(key: string, value$: Observable<T>) {
    const value: ICache<T> = {
      value$: value$.pipe(shareReplay(this.CACHE_SIZE)),
      expiry: Date.now() + this.CACHE_EXPIRY_INTERVAL,
    };
    this.cacheMap.set(key, value);
  }

  private get<T>(key: string): Observable<T> {
    return this.cacheMap.get(key).value$ as Observable<T>;
  }
}
```

I was looking for something similar.

My fork: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zgux43?file=index.ts